# How is $f$ restricted if we require that $f(A\cdot x)=g(A)f(x)+h(A)$?

Tags: functional-equations, inverse-function

EDIT: I see now that there was a mistake in my latex, causing me to ask a completely different and more trivial quesiton than I intended. I have edited the question:

**Question:**

How is the functional form of $f(x)$ restricted if we require that for any $A$ and any $x$, there exists a $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ such that $f(A\cdot x)=g(A)f(x)+h(A)$?

Also, if the $h$ over complicates things, I'm also interested in the question if we assume $h(x)=0$

**Motivation:**

If I have a general equation:
$$Af(x)=f(y)$$
and I would like to transform this into: 
$$g(A)x +h(A)=y$$

By taking the inverse of $f$:
$$f^{-1}(Af(x))=f^{-1}(f(y))$$
and then assuming that we can "take out $A$" out of the inverse (The desired property is thus a property of $f^{-1}$): 
$$g(A)\cdot f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(f(y))$$
So that we find a linear relation between $x$ and $y$. 
$$g(A)x=y$$

I'm wondering what kind of restrictions this puts on $f$.

1. I know that this would work if $f$ is homogenous, since then also $f^{-1}$ is homogenous so that we can write:
   $f^{-1}(Af(x))=A^\lambda x$
2. But I'm not sure if there are any other functional forms that satisfy the desired property.

Answer (score 1):

The identity
$$Af(x) = xg(A)+h(A)$$
implies
$$f(x) = xg(1)+h(1)$$
by taking $A=1$, so that the identity only holds for $f$ an affine function, with $h(A)\equiv f(0)$ and $h(A)\equiv f'(0)$.

Comment: But not all homogenous functions are affine, and I've shown that homogenous functions satisfy the equation. Was something wrong with my argument?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that I've made a mistake in my latex. I have reformulated the question. The constraint that I'm looking for is $f(A\cdot x)=g(A)f(x)+h(A)$, rather than $Af( x)=g(A)x+h(A)$. Also, if the $h$ overcomplicates things, I'm also interested in the question if we assume $h(x)=0$

Comment: A special case would be $g(x)=f(x)$, or $g(x)=x^\lambda$